# How to implement default UIImagePickerController's delegate of an UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller

I embedded an `UIWebView` to my view.
A default `UIImagePicker` will be presented if any file field in this webview's page is tapped.

How can I get this default picker or set its delegate?

This is my Object-C code

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://jsfiddle.net/wowaqpcf/embedded/result/"]]];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    return YES; // => set breakpoint at this line -> it doesn't stop when picker opens
}

@end
```

Or opening [this page](https://jsfiddle.net/wowaqpcf/embedded/result) by *safari* on *iPhone*, you will understand what I mean.

```html
<form>
  <input type="file">
</form>
```

I tried catching `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` but it seems that presenting this picker doesn't through delegate methods. (I thought that this picker might be presented by navigating to a special scheme)

Many thanks.

Comment: do you want to implement delegate for picker or web view? where are you getting problem

Comment: I want implement delegate for "default" picker of web view

Comment: add some more snapshot of your code or output you are getting

Comment: did you try now by only implementing `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Comment: @lalit: I think they close this API because of security reason. However, I haven't found any official site that mentions about this.
My current solution is implementing new button in webpage to call `Object-C` method that opening photo picker, then pass the picked photo to javascript callback via`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` by encoding it to base64. See my answer below for detail

Comment: this thing is not done on any platform with using custom view controller

Answer (score -2):

> **Edit:** What you want to do is not possible with default picker. If you want to crop selected image you should provide code in Javascript in your web page.

Comment: How do I get `picker` from an `UIWebView`?

When there is file field in a webview, the UIImagePicker will automatically appears if you touch it.

My question means "how to get this picker"
Sorry for the unambiguousness

Comment: No. Your code creates new picker and presents it if ANY link in page tapped. What I need is get the `default` picker when you tap to a `file field` in my web page.

Comment: open [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/wowaqpcf/embedded/result) on your _iPhone safari_

Comment: @HaidangKoltec you have to put if  condition to check when picker will open.

Comment: it doesn't load any request when picker opens. So that I cann't catch the condition. I already mentioned this way in my post

Comment: thank you for your enthusiasm. But it doesn't through any request when opening picker.
If you success by this way, could you tell me what the request's scheme is when picker opens?

Comment: Try remove all code from `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and use only `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` code.

Comment: in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`'s implementation, `viewController` is not found. And `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is deprecated from iOS `6.0`